# How to setup SandboxPostCopy actions

Tags: apex, sandbox-refresh

I had this idea that I would have a custom setting that could store the date/time a sandbox was refreshed. Then I could create a simple vf page to sit in the sidebar and give me a quick glance of the details about the Sandbox.

I built the setting, and built the vf page and they work great. I then moved onto setting the date time field in the setting when the Sandbox is refreshed. So I did some research on SandboxPostCopy and created this class:

```
global class afterCopyActions implements SandboxPostCopy
{
 global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) 
  {
   //Set the value in the custom setting
   SB_Refresh__c setting = SB_Refresh__c.getOrgDefaults();
   setting.Refresh_Date__c = System.now();
   setting.Organization_Id__c = context.organizationId();
   upsert setting;
  }
}
```

It compiles fine and the logic works in anonymous apex but when a new Sandbox is refreshed the setting did not update. There is not a lot of posts about how to effectively write this type of functionality on the Sandbox refresh. What do I need to change to make it work?

EDIT:

I found this project on [github](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-revert-user-emails-sandbox-post-copy) where his class sends the actions to another class. Maybe that is what would be needed to not do any logic and pass everything to helper classes?

Comment: Did you actually specify the class name while creating or refreshing the sandbox?

Comment: Yes, I even get an automated email saying that it finished.

Comment: I tried screen scraping to get around an issue with one of the  SF limitations to retrieve a value that I was looking for. You could screen scrape production sandbox page which lists all the SB's with their refresh dates. Not a clean solution, but it works..